# how to create a responsive timeline with css

Tags: html, css

I want to write a timeline like the image below but I do not know please guide me.
[image]

Comment: tried anything yet?

Comment: @Vishnu I can create the circle before li, but I can not make the vertical line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  right: -17px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid white;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.right::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
}

.right::after {
  left: -12px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px 0 15px;
}

.content p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">

  <div class="container right">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo ei simul congue exerci, ad nec admodum perfecto mnesarchum, vim ea mazim fierent detracto. Ea quis iuvaret expetendis his, te elit voluptua dignissim per, habeo iusto primis ea eam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container right">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo ei simul congue exerci, ad nec admodum perfecto mnesarchum, vim ea mazim fierent detracto. Ea quis iuvaret expetendis his, te elit voluptua dignissim per, habeo iusto primis ea eam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container right">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo ei simul congue exerci, ad nec admodum perfecto mnesarchum, vim ea mazim fierent detracto.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_timeline.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_timeline.asp)